# how to pass opencv mat by reference

Tags: c++, opencv, pass-by-reference

i have  1 matrix (3channel)     ->      cv::Mat channels[3];

& 3 matrix (1channel)      ->     cpu_filter0,cpu_filter90,cpu_filter120

previously I did something like this,

```
cv::Mat cpu_filter0,cpu_filter90,cpu_filter120
cv::Mat channels[] = {cpu_filter0,cpu_filter90,cpu_filter120}
```

but now I want to do like this

```
cv::Mat cpu_filter0,cpu_filter90,cpu_filter120
cv::Mat channels3[3];
channels[0] = &cpu_filter0, channels[1] = &cpu_filter90, channels[0] = &cpu_filter120;
```

or by,

```
cv::Mat channels3[] = {&cpu_filter0_0,&cpu_filter120_120,&cpu_filter240_240};
```

want to know what is the right way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying you used `cv::Mat channels[3];` to create a multi-channel Matrix? Because that is not what this does, this creates a c-style Array with 3 matrices.

First, make sure that you know the language well (C++) and how (C-style) arrays work (I found [this tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/61-arrays-part-i/), but I haven't read it).

Then, read the paragraph "Detailed Description" [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html).

To sum it up, there are different ways to create a cv::Mat, for example:

```
cv::Mat m(10, 10, CV_32FC3);
```

That creates a 10x10 matrix with 3 channels of 32-Bit floating point numbers. Other values can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180529041821/http://dovgalecs.com/blog/opencv-matrix-types). Just add "C" for your desired number of channels.

Now, how to pass them as a reference? Simply as always:

```
void my_func(cv::Mat &param) {
    // do stuff
}

// in another function
cv::Mat m(10, 10, CV_32FC3);
my_func(m);
```

Comment: yeah that helped me a lot !

Comment: I think this answer misses a main point of the cv::Mat class.  It is just a header with a managed array underneath.  It normally uses shallow copies in assignments, so passing arguments by reference is not going to save much.  The class is 2-3x the size of a pointer.

Comment: @artlessnoise In my system that is 12x. (sizeof Mat: 96 bytes. Pointer: 8 bytes)

Comment: @atakli  12x is probably correct for size; it is not clear that all of those values need to be initialized/copied.  However, it is not one million times.  Ie, it is not copying the data.  So in the example, 10*10*4 data is 400 which is much less than 96.  Often matrixes are much larger than 10x10.